# testing a model without saving it first

Tags: tensorflow

When I run this code, why do I get the warning: "saver not created?"

```
sentences=['this is one', 'this is two', 'and this is three']

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2"
embed = hub.Module(url)
embeddings = embed(sentences, signature="default", as_dict=True)["default"]

INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
```

I do not want to save anything. Can't I test the model without saving?

Answer (score -1):

This is just a "INFO" and not "Warning". Simply ignore it and it makes no difference.